# Debug command line arguments & working directory with linux remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that uses CMake, and I used Visual Studio 2022 to build it remotely on a Linux VM.

Now, when trying to debug, it starts up, but I can't find where is the option to specify the command line args and directory for the debugged process.

The documentation and examples I managed to find are only for vcxproj/sln built for Linux, but not for a CMake project. Some examples mention launch.vs.json, but I couldn't figure out to set it up for my case.

Where's that option?

Comment: I, too, um unable to provide arguments for CMake Linux debugging.  There seems to be surprisingly little interest in this problem online.

Comment: What I ended up doing was modifying main with hardcoded values for argv argc, and a call to change directory. It's bad, but it worked.

Comment: I found out how to do it in Visual Studio 2022.  I've added an answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022, click **DEBUG -> Debug and Launch Settings for [PROJECT_NAME]**. This should open an editable `launch.vs.json` file (located in the `.vs` folder in your CMake root folder) that includes "`args`" and "`cwd`" keys.

Comment: By the way, I love that the JSON file includes a "`comments`" key with a value, "Learn how to configure WSL debugging. For more info, see http://aka.ms/vslinuxdebug."  The catch-22 apparently escaped personnel at Microsoft.